# Autowired Service is Null in ResponseBody method when using PreAuthorize

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a "Foo" controller that is autowiring a "Foo" Service.

Now, when I add a PreAuthorize annotation to the controller, the view method works fine and the PreAuthorize tag only grants access to users with the ADMIN authority, but the ResponseBody method (getFoo) does not work as expected.

When using the PreAuthorize annotation, the getFoo method is unable to correctly autowire / instantiate the fooService object, which has a value of null that is causing a NPE (Null Pointer Exception).

**Issue overview:**
fooService is null (causing an NPE) when the getFoo method is called by an AJAX GET request.

However, when commenting out @PreAuthorize, fooService is no longer null when calling getFoo.

...

Here is the code:

**Foo Controller**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/foo")
@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority(T(com.foo.security.Authorities).ADMIN)")
public class FooController {

    @Autowired
    private FooService fooService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/view") 
    public String view(@AuthenticationPrincipal Principal principal) {
        return "view";
    }

    @RequestMapping(value = "/getFoo")
    @ResponseBody
    public Foo getFoo() {
        fooService.getFoo(); <- NPE happens here
    }
}
```

**Foo Service**

```
@Service("fooService")
public class FooServiceImpl implements FooService {

    @Autowired
    FooRepository fooDao;

    @Override
    public Foo getFoo() {
        return fooDao.getFoo();
    }
}
```

**Security Config**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter { ... }
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. Were you able to solve the problem in the end?

Comment: One of the controller methods is probably private

Comment: I doubt that this is the exact code you have. I suspect that the actual method `getFoo` is `private` instead of `public` or maybe even all methods are `private` instead of `public`.

Answer (score 11):

make sure all your controller methods annotated with `@RequestMapping` are not declared as private

Comment: Thank you very mutch, you solve my problem man :)

Answer (score 0):

Seems that the thread that is invoking the service doesn't have the correct security role.

Try moving the `@PreAuthorize` annotation to securize only the `view` method.

Also based on your comments I see that your problem could be that you're using two different instances of the bean. Check if you're not duplicating definitions in your context files.

Comment: I moved the @PreAuthorize annotation to only the view method. When I call the view method, only certain users with the ADMIN authority are allowed to load the view, which is correct. But when I load into the view, as a user with ADMIN authority, and then make an ajax call on the front-end to the getFoo method, then the AJAX get request returns a 500 status becuase of the NPE that is thrown due to fooService being null in that method. It is strange because removing the PreAuthorize tag from the view method then allows the getFoo method to work.

Comment: Debug it and check if the bean has been initialized in the view method

Comment: When debugging in the view method, I see that fooService has a value of FooServiceImpl. But when debugging in the getFoo method, fooService then has a value of null.

Comment: It is strange because fooService is autowiring correctly, but as soon as I introduce the @PreAuthorize annotation on any of the methods or on the FooController class itself, then i have the issue of fooService being null in the getFoo method. And if I remove the PreAuthorize tag, then getFoo has fooService properly initialized with the value of FooServiceImpl.

Comment: See my edit. Maybe you should debug bean instantiation. I bet you have two beans